# Unity movable Menu interface. Problem with collision detection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, oculus

I assume this is pretty easy but I did not find a solution yet. I have a 3D environment for VR in Unity. I have a Canvas in Worldspace which you can grab and move around like a tablet. In order to be able to touch the buttons on the canvas, I added a sphere on the tip of the controller's finger as a detector with a sphere collider. To the buttons on the canvas I added rigidboys and a boxcollider. With a onCollisionEnter Event I handle if the button and the finger are colliding and execute the onclick.Invoke() function.

It is working, the problem is if I touch the buttons they start moving and float around in the environment. If I freeze their position they won't be moved if I drag the whole menu around. How could I solve this?

Using Unity 2019.4.19f1 with Oculus OVR Plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved it with the idea of setting them to kinematic as JustARandomWibuuuu suggested. If someone might have the same problem.

I've set both to kinematic and in Project Settings → Physics → Contacts Pair Mode I had to enable all contacts.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You added `rigidbody`, so it will be a physical button, it will be affected by gravity, force, drag, ...., So it is floating because it is in 3D. You can use static rigidbody to do it

Just click true on
`Rigidbody.isKineMatic`

Comment: I also thought so but if I change it to kinematic, the collision is no longer detected. So nothing happens

Comment: Thank you for your help, I found a solution and posted it below.